# SharePoint 2013 PowerShell - how can I remove 'limited access' permissions from a DL?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

quick backstory, this site was migrated from 2010 to 2013 using the Share-Gate migration tool. Now there is this all users AD group that has all ad users in it, and since we broke inheritance on the site, I'm seeing this group is given limited access to every library. The problem with that is that it makes libraries where a user does not have any access show in the quick launch. We would like the libraries that a user does not have any access to be hidden from the quick launch for that user. I believe this limited access permission is causing the issue. Can anyone help me out?

I'm not sure how to remove it and I'm not entirely sure that will resolve the issue.

note the DL shows in the list of SiteUsers

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this one

```
$web=Get-SPWeb http://site url
$list = $web.Lists["list/library name"]
$list.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$true
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection] $spRoleAssignments=$list.RoleAssignments
for([int] $a=$spRoleAssignments.Count-1; $a -ge 0;$a--)
{
   if($spRoleAssignments[$a].Member.Name -eq "groupName")
   {
      $spRoleAssignments.Remove($a);
   }
}
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1ce2b67-661d-4272-b917-bc5eb1b39e4c/remove-group-from-document-library-using-powershell?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH! Oh did this one has plague me. This did the trick!!!!!!!!!!!!